# React: using handleclick to toggle class of mapped element by key

Tags: reactjs

I'm going through the React documentation and trying to change the condition of one element within a map based on the click of a corresponding element (associated with the same key).  Using a handleClick that looks something like this:

```
handleClick: function(e) {
    this.setState({condition: !this.state.condition});
    console.log('clicked' + e);
}
```

I have some menu items drawn this way:

```
return (
    <li key={i}>
        <a
            onClick={_this.handleClick.bind(_this, i)}
            data-nav={'nav-' + el.label.en.toLowerCase()}>
            {el.label.en}
        </a>
    </li>
);
```

And some submenu sections whose class I want to toggle based on click of the above:

```
return (
    <section
        className={_this.state.condition ? "active" :""}
        key={i}
        id={'nav-' + el.label.en.toLowerCase()}>
        <ul>
            <GetChildren data={el.children} />
        </ul>
    </section>
);
```

Right now, obviously, when I click the first, all  elements toggle their class. For the life of me, I can't figure out how to pass the key, so that if I'm clicking on item 1, the section with key {1} gets an "active" class, and others do not.  In javascript with jquery I could get at it using the data-attribute.  I'm sure react has a simple way that I'm just not understanding.

Comment: you need to have a condition attribute associated with each and every element of your data seperately. Having a common state attribute will lead to change in all of them

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by setting the active key in your state object instead of toggling a condition.

So in your `handleClick`

```
this.setState({
    activeKey: e
});
```

then in your `<section>`

```
className={_this.state.activeKey === i ? "active" : ""}
```

Comment: This is perfect, and really elegant. Thank you.